# Grouping by ID in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can anyone help me with the following aggregate operation in mongodb: having a collection of items with ids and group ids, group them by group ids. For example, for collection of items:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "group_id": 10,
    "data": "some_data",
    "name": "first"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "group_id": 10,
    "data": "some_data",
    "name": "second"
},
{
    "id": 3
    "group_id": 20,
    "data": "some_data",
    "name": "third"
}
```

Create new collection of groups with the following structure:

```
    {
    "id": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "group_id": 10,
            "data": "some_data",
            "name": "first"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "group_id": 10,
            "data": "some_data",
            "name": "second"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "group_id": 20,
            "data": "some_data",
            "name": "third"
        }
    ]
}
```

The corresponding snippet with Java and spring-data-mongodb will also be appreciated.
In fact I'm doing the same right now with Java and want to move this logic to mongo for paging optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the folowwing simple [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation:

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: {
       _id : "$group_id",
       items : { "$push" : "$$ROOT" }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

When you want to output the data from the aggregation into a new collection use the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator